# Implementing a trait for closures results in bound/concrete lifetime mismatch

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I want to implement a trait for closures of a specific type. Here is a minimal example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=270da6a672e2217812d10b7217ad1f62&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self, x: &u32);
}

impl<F> Foo for F
    where F: Fn(&u32)
{
    fn foo(&self, x: &u32) {
        self(x)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _: &FnOnce(&u32) = &|x| {};   // works
    let _: &Foo          = &|x| {};   // doesn't work
}
```

It results in this error:

```
error: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <[closure@<anon>:16:29: 16:35] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r u32,)>>::Output == ()`:
 expected bound lifetime parameter ,
    found concrete lifetime [--explain E0271]
  --> <anon>:16:28
   |>
16 |>     let _: &Foo          = &|x| {};
   |>                            ^^^^^^^
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Foo` for `[closure@<anon>:16:29: 16:35]`
note: required for the cast to the object type `Foo`

error: type mismatch: the type `[closure@<anon>:16:29: 16:35]` implements the trait `std::ops::Fn<(_,)>`, but the trait `for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(&'r u32,)>` is required (expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter ) [--explain E0281]
  --> <anon>:16:28
   |>
16 |>     let _: &Foo          = &|x| {};
   |>                            ^^^^^^^
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Foo` for `[closure@<anon>:16:29: 16:35]`
note: required for the cast to the object type `Foo`
```

I already tried to explicitly add the HRTB to the `where` clause like this:

```
where F: for<'a> Fn(&'a u32)
```

But it didn't help. I also declared the lifetime on the `impl` block instead, like this:

```
impl<'a, F> Foo for F
    where F: Fn(&'a u32) { ... }
```

But this results in a lifetime error within the `impl` block. I *think* that those errors are right and the lifetime parameter can't be declared on the `impl` block.

How can I fix this example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this part of the error:

> [...] implements the trait `std::ops::Fn<(_,)>`, but the trait `for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(&'r u32,)>` is required

I think that basically there's not enough code to allow types to be properly inferred. Adding an explicit type annotation allows the example to be compiled:

```
let _: &Foo          = &|x: &u32| {};
```

Comment: Hmm, so why can the compiler not infer that?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson I'm interested in this, too! Your and Shepmaster's answer already helped me! Adding the explicit type isn't too bad in my case and it works now. It's really difficult to decide which answer to accept :<  ... Maybe the one that can explain why the type inference fails ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Here's a partial answer, starting with an interesting experiment:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self, x: &u32);
}

impl<F> Foo for F
    where F: Fn(&u32)
{
    fn foo(&self, x: &u32) {
        self(x)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f1: &Fn(&u32) = &|_x| {}; 
    let f2: &Foo = &f1;
    // but this fails:
    // let f3: &Foo = &|_x| {};
    f2.foo(&3);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d26c09b64a220c00b95a131309209227&version=nightly&backtrace=0))

All I've done is change the `FnOnce` to `Fn` for consistency with the trait, and assign your first closure to a binding of type `&Foo` - and this one work.

This tells me that the trait itself is fine - it's a problem inferring the type of the closure when making the trait object.  Going back to the error, we're told that the closure implements `std::ops::Fn<(_,)>`, but `for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(&'r u32,)>` is required.  This means that the first thing you tried (adding the `for<'r>...` to the trait) didn't have any effect because the trait *already* requires this.

At this point I'm stuck - I don't think I understand the inference rules for closures in enough detail to see either why there's a difference, or how to make it work.  I'm hoping someone will come and fill that in!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no idea what I'm doing.

The following works:

```
trait Foo<'a> {
    fn foo(&self, x: &'a u32);
}

impl<'a, F> Foo<'a> for F where F: Fn(&'a u32) {
    fn foo(&self, x: &'a u32) {
        self(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the trait (e.g. `let f: &Foo = &|x| {}; f.foo(&3);`) becomes impossible with this solution. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=563c415937fa42d5311c7a08cdaae54f&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: Well, it's above my power level - just thought you might not have checked this option out.